# In Mysq how can i find range from points table?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i find available ranges from points table given that a range is separated from anther if the incremental value is more than 0.25
(I have points table i want to generate range table)

```
POINTS table
+----+------+------+------------+
| id | sph  |  cyl | othertbl_id|
+----+------+------+------------+
|  1 | 0    | 0    |     1      |
|  2 | 0    | 0.25 |     1      |
|  3 | 0    | 0.50 |     1      |
|  4 | 0    | 1.00 |     1      |
|  5 | 0.25 | 0    |     1      |
|  6 | 0.25 | 0.25 |     1      |
|  7 | 0.25 | 0.50 |     1      |
|  8 | 0.25 | 1.00 |     1      |
|  9 | 3.25 | 0    |     1      |
| 10 | 3.25 | 0.25 |     1      |
| 11 | 3.50 | 0    |     1      |
| 12 | 3.50 | 0.25 |     1      |
| 13 | 3.75 | 0    |     1      |
| 14 | 3.75 | 0.25 |     1      |
+----+-------------+------------+
```

i want generate range table that looks like this

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
| id | min_sph  |  max_sph | min_cyl  |  max_cyl |othertbl_id |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
|  1 | 0        | 0.25     |     0    |  1.00    |      1     |
|  2 | 3.25     | 3.75     |     0    |  0.25    |      1     |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Similar case scenario to make this much easier to understand

the range table i generated earlier is the result i want.lets say that othertbl is product table and each product has different stock count at each range of points, lets say t-shirt A is available form age 0-2 and height from 30-50 and also available for age 28-30 and height 100-120 all point of these ranges are for the same t-shirt row. if the difference in ages is more than one year or difference in height more than 10 is considered a new range

in this case points table will look like this

```
+----+------+------+------------+
| id | age  |  hgt | othertbl_id|
+----+------+------+------------+
|  1 | 0    | 30   |     1      |
|  2 | 0    | 40   |     1      |
|  3 | 0    | 50   |     1      |
|  4 | 1    | 30   |     1      |
|  5 | 1    | 40   |     1      |
|  6 | 1    | 50   |     1      |
|  7 | 2    | 30   |     1      |
|  8 | 2    | 40   |     1      |
|  9 | 2    | 50   |     1      |
| 10 | 28   | 100  |     1      |
| 11 | 28   | 110  |     1      |
| 12 | 28   | 120  |     1      |
| 13 | 29   | 100  |     1      |
| 14 | 29   | 110  |     1      |
| 14 | 29   | 120  |     1      |
| 14 | 30   | 100  |     1      |
| 14 | 30   | 110  |     1      |
| 14 | 30   | 120  |     1      |
+----+-------------+------------+
```

And range table will look like this

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
| id | min_age  |  max_age | min_hgt  |  max_hgt |othertbl_id |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
|  1 | 0        | 2        |     30   |  50      |      1     |
|  2 | 28       | 30       |     100  |  120     |      1     |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Where does `3.50` go?  What have you tried?

Comment: what should be in `id` and `othertbl_id` columns in result? I mean for sph[0-0.25] why it should display 1 and 1?

Comment: It looks like your points rows are somehow segmented into two groups, with id values 1-8 and then 9-14.  Can you explain in more detail how this works?

Comment: @OllieJones Please check Question after edit and your are right with the segments

Comment: Solving this clustering problem in SQL involves comparing consecutive rows, which requires a self-join. MySql makes it harder than other SQL variants to do this, because of the lack of `ROWNUM` support. The query, *if* it can be developed, will be a nasty hairball. You may want to add a column to help distinguish the cluster ranges instead.

Answer (score 0):

question is not very clear, anyway, here is one variant, which returns "something" very close to desired result:

```
select min(id) as id, sph as min_sph, (select min(sph) from points as b where b.sph>a.sph) as max_sph, min(cyl) as min_cyl, max(cyl) as max_cyl, othertbl_id as othertbl_id
from points as a
group by othertable_id, sph
```

result is:

```
id  minsph  maxsph  mincyl  maxcyl  othertable_id
1   0       0.25    0       1       1
5   0.25    3.25    0       1       1
9   3.25    3.5     0       0.25    1
11  3.5     3.75    0       0.25    1
13  3.75    (null)  0       0.25    1
```

Comment: the range table i generated earlier is the result i want. saying that othertbl is product table  and each product has different stock count at each range of points, lets say it t-shirts form age 0-5 and height from 0-50 and also available for age 10-30 and height 100-190 all point of these ranges are for the same t-shirt row.

Comment: @Bakly I've changed query a little bit, try it on your real database, should work

Comment: @llya Bursov this selects from each point to anther as a range i need the range to be seprated on difference more than 0.25 if the is 0.25 the are in the same range check my edit on my question for clarification Thank you